# System.InvalidOperationException on Button.Content in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Probably a stupid thing but I found the answer nowhere...

I have the following code in my C# WPF Project:

```
string timer = "5:00"; 
Button.Content = timer;
```

and it gives me `System.InvalidOperationException` once code execution reaches this point. It also doesn't work with `Button.Content = "5:00";` but funny enough in another function this code

```
string newLabel = Math.Floor(timerSec / 60f).ToString() + ":" + (timerSec % 60).ToString("0#");
Button.Content = newLabel;
```

works just fine. What am I missing?

**//edit:** the question cause confusion because it is pseudo code and I didn't think too much when I put it. here is how the button is actually defined:

```
<Viewbox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">
     <Button x:Name="_5v5OwnBlueButton" Content="5:00" Margin="5" />
</Viewbox>
```

Comment: Is `Button` an instance of `System.Windows.Controls.Button`?

Comment: @bash.d: I think `Content` property comes for this control only.

Comment: is the pseudo code you posted or did you name your member `Button` its usually not good practice to name members/variable the same as classes that are accessible within your codebase.

Comment: Is your first snippet called before `InitialiseComponents()`?

Comment: @sa_ddam213 this is what I mean!!

Comment: it is pseudo code. i didn't think enough when I put it. i put the real definition into the question now (gonna be open source anyway once it has reached a "it's working" stage) :)

Comment: @Psytronic: no, `InitialiseComponent()` is called first thing in `MainWindow()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using threads?

Try this:

```
string timer = "5:00"; 
     this.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (Action) () => 
            {

              Button.Content = timer;
            });
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but I'm not using threads. This is in fact my first C# application ever :)

Comment: hm, turns out I was wrong. Obviously changing the UI in timer callbacks is indeed using (implicit) threads. Your answer got me on the right track. Thanks!<br/> I use this code now:     `Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
                      DispatcherPriority.Background,
                        new Action(() => _5v5OwnBlueButton.Content = buffTimer)
                );` (your code was syntactically wrong).

Comment: You should call CheckAccess() to see if you really need to invoke first.   if (this.Dispatcher.CheckAccess()) { //Invoke Button.Content = timer; } else { Button.Content = timer; }